# Font for the minus sign created by $-6$ (hyphen in math mode)

Tags: fonts, fontspec, unicode-math

I want to specify the font (in the example below: Times New Roman) for all minus signs, regardless of whether they were created with the Unicode character "2212 or with a hyphen in math mode.

If I add "2212 to the range option of `\setmathfont`, it works when I write my text using the proper unicode character "minus sign". See the first two 6 in my example.

But when I write $-6$ (here - is an ordinary hyphen), the output is a correct minus sign, but not in Times New Roman. See the last 6 in my example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage[silent]{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\RequirePackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{STIXTwoMath}[]
\setmathfont{Times New Roman}[ range = { up/{num,latin,Latin}, "2212 } ]

\begin{document}

%% Minus ("2212) in source code:
−6 and $−6$

%% Hyphen ("002D) in source code:
-6 and $-6$ 

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Does anyone know how I can get "access" to the hyphen in $ environments?

Comment: You want the input to be a hyphen, but the output to be the minus sign of Times New Roman?

Comment: Yes, exactly. But only in math mode: `$-6$` should become a proper "minus 6", but the minus sign in Times New Roman and not from STIX.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am unsure why that is, but if you say `range = { "2212, \minus }`, it works, but you really need to state both `"2212` and `\minus`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage[silent]{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\RequirePackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}
\setmathfont{Times New Roman}[ 
    range = { "2212, \minus } 
]

\begin{document}

%% Minus ("2212) in source code:
−6 and $−6$

%% Hyphen ("002D) in source code:
-6 and $-6$ 

\end{document}
```

[image]

So, you might want to do something like this to select the same font for plus and minus sign:

```
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage[silent]{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\RequirePackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}
\setmathfont{Times New Roman}[ 
    range = { "2212, \minus, "002B } 
]

\begin{document}

-6 and $-6$ 

+6 and $+6$ 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you so much! The `\minus` solves the problem indeed.

Comment: @Simon It does, but it feels like a bug as you need to select both `\minus` and `"2212`.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you write `\textnormal{-}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\setmathfont{STIXTwoMath}[]
\setmathfont{Times New Roman}[ range = { up/{num,latin,Latin}, "2212 } ]

\begin{document}

%% Minus ("2212) in source code:
−6 and $−6$

%% Hyphen ("002D) in source code:
-6 and $\textnormal{-}6$ 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, Mico. But I don't want to change the input `$-6$'. I'm looking for a global solution. (My example was a minimal working example taken from a much bigger project.)